# GRUB Windows not booting

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

I’m using Parrot OS in dual boot with Windows 10. One day Windows just stopped booting from GRUB with next error:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a034d0,0)/PCI(1,1)/PCI(0,0)/UnknownMessaging(17)/HD(1,800,32000,f452754febf9674d,2,2)
/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire 
error: cannot load image.
I have tried using boot-repair to fix this but it didn’t help. Here is its log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6SXYdWxwxh/
```

When I try to boot Windows directly from BIOS, the screen just blinks for a second and nothing happens. Linux is working fine.

have tried using boot-repair to fix this but it didn’t help. Here is its log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6SXYdWxwxh/

Secure boot in BIOS is set to off.

Comment: Can you not boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu. Grub only boots working Windows.

Comment: When I try booting it from UEFI the screen just blinks for a second and nothing happens.

Comment: If Windows does not directly boot from UEFI boot menu, then that is a Windows issue. You may be able to press f8 to get to Windows repair console after using f12 to boot it. But if not then you need your Windows repair recovery flash drive to fix it. Windows 8/10 UEFI fixes, if no repair flash drive you may be able to download Window installer and use it.
http://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader

Comment: When I try to run bootrec /fixboot command it says that access is denied. Windows auto recovery from installation usb also appears not to be working.

Comment: Did you delete Windows? While Boot-Repair cannot fix Windows issues, the Summary Report will show details on your installs. Post link to Summary Report in your question above.

Comment: Posted the link. No, I did not delete Windows, it just stopped booting (probably after automatic update).

Comment: Windows boot problems are technically off topic here in Linu&Unix.SE, but the fact that the boot file path includes `UnknownMessaging(17)`makes me suspect a firmware issue... Wild guess: go to BIOS settings, see if there is anything related to NVMe support, and if you find something, make sure it's enabled?

Comment: Just looked up bios nvme settings, there is nothing to enable. Plus the system was working perfectly fine for about half a year in its current configuration.

Comment: Windows looks normal. UEFI boot entry for "Windows Boot Manager", boot files in ESP, and standard NTFS partition for Windows with other supporting partitions. You probably need to go to a site that is for Windows support where users will know more about Windows issues.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Parrot OS and update the GRUB config.

- First run `sudo os-prober` to detect installed OSes
- Then run `sudo update-grub` to update the configuration.

Reboot and select Windows in the GRUB menu.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn’t help.